# Change of basis matrix with basis vectors multiplied by constants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm to write a change of basis matrix from basis e to f, where e is the standard basis and f is given by:

$f_1 = 1/\sqrt{3} * \underline{e}(-1, 1)$

$f_2 = 1/\sqrt{2} * \underline{e}(1, 1)$

So the transformation matrix from f to e would be:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{array} \right) $

And we get e to f by taking the inverse. I'm wondering if there is a away to get rid of the ugly square roots to make the calculations easier when calculating the change of basis matrix?